# Favicon won't appear on Google search results, after migration to https

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, favicon

I've recently migrated a website of mine to https and now the favicon in Google's search results shows the general globe instead of the site's favicon.

This is how the favicon is defined:

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/favicon.ico">
```

The favicon is actually defined the same way as the http version of my site, I've made sure that it is accessible and the favicon is shown correctly on Chrome tabs.

I've also made sure that the main page of the website is indexed in Google Search Console.

Pages that still show up in the search results with their http version (yet to be crawled), have the correct favicon.

Any ideas?

Comment: Cross-posting is [not allowed on the Stack Exchange network](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068). You should delete your question at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57515510/favicon-wont-appear-on-google-search-results-after-moving-from-http-to-https).

Comment: My question here is SEO related

Comment: You cannot pay the same question at two stack exchange sites at the same time. You need to delete the one posted at stack overflow as it is off topic there.

Comment: I would create an absolute URL for the favicon, including HTTPS protocol.

Comment: @Evgeniy Already did that a few days ago. No change.

Comment: @RonTesler Did you checked your logfiles after you changed favicon url to an absolute? If Googlebot doesn't visited it, you can't await it would appear in SERP. I would bet on Googlebot doesnt visited it yet and that is why you realized no changes - few day are just too few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to unblock Google Image's crawler from scanning my website.

The `robots.txt` file looked like so -

```
‎User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /‎
```

I removed the above lines from the `robots.txt` file and Google started showing the favicon on the search results within 2-3 days.

I repeated the process for another domain that had the same issue, and got the same successful results.