# Google search not showing logo in search result

Tags: google-search, favicon

My website when searched on Google does not have logo in search result.
[image]

```
<!-- Icons / Favicon -->
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="any">
<link rel="icon" href="/icon.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/192x192.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://offerstreet.in/">
```

What I need to do?

Comment: Similar question: [Google search does not display my favicons](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/137519/google-search-does-not-display-my-favicons)

Comment: Another similar question: [Favicon won't appear on Google search results, after migration to https](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/124603/favicon-wont-appear-on-google-search-results-after-migration-to-https)

Comment: Another similar question: [Wrong favicon displayed on Google's mobile SERP](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/126451/wrong-favicon-displayed-on-googles-mobile-serp)

Comment: Another similar question: [Favicon is not showing for mobile Google search result when using Cloudflare](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/127951/favicon-is-not-showing-for-mobile-google-search-result-when-using-cloudflare)

Answer (score 1):

I checked your website using `https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker`

There's a notice that the image for your **favicon.ico** is ill-formed. The URL for it might also return an error page with a `200` HTTP status instead of a regular `404` status.

I recommend creating a new favicon, and make sure there aren't any crawl errors in Google Search Console for your favicon's URL.